# how to make real time notification in android using retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I want to make real-time notification in my android app, but I don't know how to make it real-time and connected to the database

how to make my app can get/access data change from the database every time the database changing even when we didn't open the app

let's say every time admin sending notification, it will send data to database and it has column "read" and it will set to 0 and then user's app will immediately receive notification where the column "read" is 0, and when user opens the notification it will open an activity and change column "read" from database to 1.

Comment: I have achieved the same thing using the firebase Cloud Messaging service. Using following link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: @Lukas thanks for your reply, but i need it using retrofit 2, actually i am just confused how to make my app keep accessing database even without open it, about the connection to database i think i can handle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either firebase cloud messaging or user background notification service with web socket connection

Comment: i still don't understand how web socket works, is i need to make a function in my API to send message to my app every time when admin changing data, and then my app will receive it ? or i don't need to work on my API , and it just the matter of my android app code ?

Comment: FCM will be better for you web socket are more advanced ,you will integrate both your API an android app to single project in firebase so any change in your data you can send notification

Comment: i wish i could use FCM, but my project is prohibited to use firebase things

Comment: this is library for web socket in android you will use it with background service
https://github.com/hosopy/actioncable-client-java
and you can search for how to implement web socket in your API

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this type of real-time communication like,

1. Socket.
2. MQTT Protocol.
3. WebRTC.
4. Firebase Live Database.

Also, you can achieve this feature by sending notification from your admin panel to the user's mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

A common way is to implement Firebase(FCM) in your application and on your server. You can see how to implement FCM using this Offical documentation help Link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/